# I have moved default files to other folder accidentally and now machine not starting

Tags: grub2

I have executed following command accidentally on Ubuntu 18.04, now no command(ls, sudo, cp, mv) is working except cd

```
 sudo mv /* /myfolder/subfolder/
```

I have tried to restart the machine and now getting black screen with following text:

```
error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
grub rescue>
```

Can somebody help me to restore my machine as all of blockchain projects are insdie. Thanks in advance.

Comment: boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media), `mount` your partition, then `mv` (move) the files back where they should be.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have done this all files moved now performed starting check, not doing any thing after showing Started GNOME Display manager status to [OK]., I have tried to press Alt+F2 but no response.